# Error when trying to execute ISR Execution

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I did everything the same as usual. But this time I got this error on ISR Execution?
I restarted, reinstalled...

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-627ce27cdb89> in <module>()
      5 
      6 from ISR.models import RDN, RRDN
----> 7 rrdn = RRDN(weights='gans')
      8 rdn = RDN(weights='noise-cancel')
      9 print("De-noising...")

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers)
    649   """
    650   if 'keras_version' in f.attrs:
--> 651     original_keras_version = f.attrs['keras_version'].decode('utf8')
    652   else:
    653     original_keras_version = '1'

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: `bytes()` has `.decode()`, `str()` has `.encode()`...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.